# Operators $T_i$ in matrix form.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space and let $T$ be a $K$-linear map $T: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$. Denote by $T_i$ the linear operator on $V^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes n}$ which acts on the $i$th and $(i+1)$th factors and acts trivially on other factors. I would like to understand the matrix form of $T_i$. For example, let $V$ be $2$ dimensional and $e_1, e_2$ be its standard basis. Suppose that with respect to $e_1\otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2$, $T$ is
\begin{align*}
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} \mu_{{1,1}}&\mu_{{1,2}}&\mu_{{1,3}}&\mu_{
{1,4}}\\  \mu_{{2,1}}&\mu_{{2,2}}&\mu_{{2,3}}&\mu_{{2
,4}}\\  \mu_{{3,1}}&\mu_{{3,2}}&\mu_{{3,3}}&\mu_{{3,4
}}\\  \mu_{{4,1}}&\mu_{{4,2}}&\mu_{{4,3}}&\mu_{{4,4}}
\end {array} \right] .
\end{align*}
Let $n=3$. I obtained that, with respect to $$e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2, e_1 \otimes e_2 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2 \otimes e_2,$$
\begin{align*}
T_1 =  \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} \mu_{{1,1}}&0&\mu_{{1,2}}&0&\mu_{{1,3
}}&0&\mu_{{1,4}}&0\\ 0&\mu_{{1,1}}&0&\mu_{{1,2}}&0&
\mu_{{1,3}}&0&\mu_{{1,4}}\\ \mu_{{2,1}}&0&\mu_{{2,2}
}&0&\mu_{{2,3}}&0&\mu_{{2,4}}&0\\ 0&\mu_{{2,1}}&0&
\mu_{{2,2}}&0&\mu_{{2,3}}&0&\mu_{{2,4}}\\ \mu_{{3,1}
}&0&\mu_{{3,2}}&0&\mu_{{3,3}}&0&\mu_{{3,4}}&0\\ 0&
\mu_{{3,1}}&0&\mu_{{3,2}}&0&\mu_{{3,3}}&0&\mu_{{3,4}}
\\ \mu_{{4,1}}&0&\mu_{{4,2}}&0&\mu_{{4,3}}&0&\mu_{{4
,4}}&0\\ 0&\mu_{{4,1}}&0&\mu_{{4,2}}&0&\mu_{{4,3}}&0
&\mu_{{4,4}}\end {array} \right],
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
T_2 = \left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} \mu_{{1,1}}&\mu_{{1,2}}&\mu_{{1,3}}&
\mu_{{1,4}}&0&0&0&0\\ \mu_{{2,1}}&\mu_{{2,2}}&\mu_{{
2,3}}&\mu_{{2,4}}&0&0&0&0\\ \mu_{{3,1}}&\mu_{{3,2}}&
\mu_{{3,3}}&\mu_{{3,4}}&0&0&0&0\\ \mu_{{4,1}}&\mu_{{
4,2}}&\mu_{{4,3}}&\mu_{{4,4}}&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&\mu_
{{1,1}}&\mu_{{1,2}}&\mu_{{1,3}}&\mu_{{1,4}}\\ 0&0&0&0
&\mu_{{2,1}}&\mu_{{2,2}}&\mu_{{2,3}}&\mu_{{2,4}}\\ 0
&0&0&0&\mu_{{3,1}}&\mu_{{3,2}}&\mu_{{3,3}}&\mu_{{3,4}}
\\ 0&0&0&0&\mu_{{4,1}}&\mu_{{4,2}}&\mu_{{4,3}}&\mu_{
{4,4}}\end {array} \right].
\end{align*}
Are these computations correct? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations indeed appear to be correct. Your results for $T_1,T_2$ can be confirmed using the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), since we have
$$
T_2 = I_2 \otimes T, \quad T_1 = T \otimes I_2.
$$